# How can we set the lenient option in hibernate-search query builder

Tags: elasticsearch, hibernate-search

We are using hibernate search api for elastic search. I came across `lenient` option in elastic search: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html but unable to figure out how can we set this through hibernate search.

Some of the fields in elastic search are boolean, and range, and we don't want to search through them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option in Hibernate Search at the moment.

In Hibernate Search 5, you can [write your whole query as JSON](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#_queries) in order to take advantage of native options. That will require you to write *everything* as JSON, though, not just the simple-query-string query.

In Hibernate Search 6, you [write just the simple-query-string predicate as JSON](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-predicate-extensions-elasticsearch-from-json) to take advantage of a native option in this predicate and continue using the Hibernate Search DSL for other predicates in the same query, which should be more convenient.

If you need the feature in the DSL, you can create a [JIRA ticket](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/projects/HSEARCH) and it will be addressed in Hibernate Search 6 if it makes it to the top of the priority list. If you need it before then, you can of course submit a pull request. Note that new features should go into Hibernate Search 6 (master branch), not Hibernate Search 5 which is currently in maintenance mode.

Comment: Thanks. Will just use queryBuilder.all().except() to exclude the fields that are not simple query string.